Unable to integrate grpc with spring cloud gateway
I am trying to integrate grpc with the spring cloud gateway.
I want to hit a grpc gateway URL with a proto file and redirect it to the grpc service.
My gateway config looks like below
...
..
..
server:
  port: 8080
  http2:
    enabled: true
spring:
  application:
    name: API Gateway
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
    web-environment: false
    web-application-type: reactive
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    allow-circular-references: true
  cloud:
      gateway:
          filter:
            remove-hop-by-hop:
              headers:
                - connection
                - keep-alive
                - transfer-encoding
                - proxy-authenticate
                - proxy-authorization
                - x-application-context
                - upgrade
          httpclient:
            wiretrap: true
            ssl:
              use-insecure-trust-manager: true
          httpserver:
            wiretrap: true
          routes:
            - id: grpc-test
              uri: ${service_grpc_url:grpc://grpc-test:50053}
              predicates:
              - Path= /grpc-api/**
              filters:
              - RewritePath=/grpc-api(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
       ..
..
..

On deploying the above changes, when I hit the below gateway URL
grpc://<api-gateway-host>:8080/grpc-api
It does not redirect to grpc://grpc-test:50053 . I get "service unavailable error".
I am able to reach the grpc service pod directly by hitting grpc://grpc-test:50053, but it is not redirecting via api-gateway.
I am using springboot version 3.2.3.
The spring cloud version is 2023.0.0.
I have added the below dependencies
implementation (group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
   implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security')
   implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
   implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
   implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-openfeign-core'

Not sure if have missed out on anything. Do I need to add any grpc specific dependency?

drive-by comment (unfamiliar with Java|Spring) Have you tried to pare this back to a minimal configuration? Why isn't the (destination?) uri just uri: grpc://grpc-test:50053? Can you drop the filters temporarily? Verbose debugging would be useful (perhaps using gRPCurl)

tried removing filters and modified uri. it doesnt work

issue got resolved after enabling ssl in the grpc server and adding certificates on both grpc-server and api-gateway.
